# Android images in table layout

Tags: android, uiimageview, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a dynamic table layout in my Android app. Number of rows and cols may vary, but each "cell" should contain an image. What would be the proper way of populating my table with those images but scaling them so regardless of number of rows and cols they scale to perfectly fit the table and keep their aspect ration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [Gridview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) for this, check the Android docs.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got you right.

Try [setStretchAllColumns(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setStretchAllColumns%28boolean%29) to stretch all of your columns. So your columns fit on every number of columns.